# restrict user host settings to socket connection only

Tags: mysql, linux

Is there a way to restrict a user's host setting so that (s)he can only connect by socket and not TCP/IP? I'd like to have this setting for the root account.

**edit:** As Abdul Manaf pointed out `skip-networking` can be used to turn off TCP/IP connectivity altogether. But can it be done on a user account basis?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to listen MySQL connections only using socket add a line in my.cnf and restart MySQL server.

```
skip-networking
```

This is recommended practice when there is no reason for it to listen on TCP.